# ActiveMQ - how to set persistency from config?

Tags: activemq-classic

I have a topic and three queues in activeMQ. Producer is publishing the message to the topic and it's routing the same message in these three queues. Now my question is:

1. I haven't set persistency in producer and I don't want to because of some project limitation. How caan I set persistency for the topic and queues from ActiveMQ broker? I am using ActiveMQ 5.15.12 version.
2. Can I set persistency for one queue and don't set for another?
3. What will happen if I don't use the persistency? I know there have chances of losing messages during broker restart but is there any other way to overcome this issue?

Comment: Topic persistence is in part controlled by the client (if you set a `subscriptionID`) then on reconnect you will get any pending messages. If you don't any messages generated when that client is offline will be lost and never delivered to the client. Queues by default hold a copy of the message till its ack'd. If nothing does then the queue will grow and grow till it OOM's I'm personally not sure you can change the default queue behaviour.

Comment: I don't believe that ActiveMQ provides a way to control message persistence at the broker level -- except "on" and "off". There are no finer-grained controls I'm aware of. I could be wrong, of course. If I'm right, it might be possible to create an ActiveMQ broker plugin that changes the client's persistence flag as the message is accepted; but I haven't actually tried :/